# Get google place id of current city in android

Tags: android

How to get place_id of user's city using google service in android? getCurrentPlace return list of places near divese, I can't get city from where.

Answer (score 0):

This  repo may help you.https://github.com/Cutta/FusedLocationApi_Example

You can get country, city postcode, country code etc.